# IE7 Javascript Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to develop a application that has quite a bit of client side based scripts.  The page has sections that interact with each other based on different inputs. The problem is when you get alot of content on the page the page slows down DRAMATICALLY in IE7 due to the poor javascript engine integrated with this browswer and also partly, becasue there is quite a bit more data on the page.

I am already using web services for anything I can, JQuery with ID based selectors and as little effects and animations as I can.

Do you guys have any tips that I could use for optimization of this?

Comment: It would help to see your code, or at least know *what you're doing*.

Comment: Yeah, I've fought IE7 before. Really hard to help without seeing your code.

Comment: Definitely need to see some code.

Comment: Why do you care about the engine in IE7? Think it's likely to be fixed to be as fast as IE8? Don't think so. Test your app on IE8 and report any slowness to Microsoft, ASAP, so you have some chance of getting it fixed by SP1.

Comment: IE8's JavaScript is faster than IE7's. But people are still in IE7 (and even IE6). God luck on that "reporting slowness to Microsoft" thing. People have been doing that for years and what's happened? The OTHER browsers made their JavaScript interpreters faster!

Comment: Well the problem is the software I'm developing is used by fortune 1000 and below and in these large corporate enviroments they typically adapt upgrades pretty slowly.  The performance is acceptable in ie8.  Sorry about no code, there is about 6k plus lines of it.

Comment: OK, no code, but what are you doing? How are you making changes to the DOM?

Comment: ... Like Joe Blow will be using IE8 before 2012 anyway.  I've still got 20% on IE6 on two of my sites.

Comment: I think it's more likely people will move from IE7 to IE8 than from IE6 to IE8. All those damned intranet apps based on IE6 have frozen a bunch of corporations. The company my brother works for is struggling to get loose from IE6. He says they'll go right to IE8, but they still have some things that break when they try to leave IE6.

Answer (score 3):

Run your code in a profiler and see what it is actually doing. See where your time is spent. IE8 provides IE7 compatibility and a decent profiler included in its Developer Tools.

To do the profiling in IE7 directly you will have to mess around with Visual Web Developer or the debugger bundled with MS Office. More fooling around is necessary, but it is possible to get it to work. Every time I have needed to set this up on a new computer it has taken me an hour or more to figure out the magic incantation to make it work, but it is doable.

Comment: Well that wouldn't really help if his problem exists in IE7 but not IE8.

Comment: Does the IE7 compatibility mode have the same speed profile as a native IE7? If so, profiling would be a great start.

Comment: No, it just conforms to the way IE7 does things, but it definitely does not have the same speed.

Comment: Profiling will still give you an idea of where you should start looking. Unfortunately the problem might be side effects of DOM manipulations. The amount of time it takes to say do inputbox.checked=true varies wildly between browsers (Opera seems to be particularly slow).

Answer (score 3):

A couple off-the-wall suggestions...

1. Flash as coprocessor. If you have computationally expensive things to do, you can hand them off to Flash. The ActionScript is going to be faster than IE's lousy JS. However, be aware that if you transfer much data back and forth between JS and Flash, it's very slow.
2. Google Gears. You can speed things up with web workers. When you detect IE7, say that upgrading to IE8 or installing Google Gears will improve the experience.
3. Possibly Silverlight could be used as a coprocessor. I don't have experience with it, however.

Can you even tell what's slow? Is it when you touch the DOM?

Comment: Added a mention of Silverlight, although it's just a guess as to whether it would work.

Comment: can't use silverlight due to same reason as above.  I wish i could!

Comment: the slowness I see is when carrying out actiosn on the page such as collasping sections

Comment: Do you animate the collapses?

Comment: no not at all...its not only that action thats just one that i knew people would know...its like any kind of event on the page

Comment: i also haven't heard about the Flash idea, sounds feasible, and flash is everywhere.  about Gears, I don't see how it could help, since the worker threads also use the same lousy JScript interpreter as explained here: http://groups.google.com/group/gears-users/browse_thread/thread/33ad4d515fb4a51b/a8c62c1fb4858ddd also saw your question here: http://ajaxian.com/archives/gears-03-released-and-google-io-videos-on-ajax-related-content-available

Comment: But some people insist the workers do work because they're on a different thread. I'm not convinced the problems here are JS, though. Might be IE7's DOM handling.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of feel like maybe some of these answers might be missing the obvious.

What is the efficiency of the algorithm you are using? Linear? Logorithmic? exponential? It seems to me, that if it's the JAVASCRIPT that's getting slower, as the document gets larger, then it's the efficiency of YOUR code that's the problem, not MS's. IE javascript is slow, but what makes you so sure that it's specifically a problem with that browser? Do other javascript engines do okay with it?

Without knowing a single thing about what you're doing or how you're doing it, one way to go is to trade off memory usage for speed- Cache previous results, and other optimization strategies which you can find lying around if you read this book or that website about programming.

Another thing to keep in mind is that dom interaction is really slow. If you can reorganize your code to achieve the same thing, but with fewer manipulations in the dom, that will improve performance

Comment: Yeah, we're just guessing without the code. My biggest problems in IE7 have been with animated visualizations (where I had to bring the target framerate down to 1/4 that of the other browsers) and anything that uses Canvas. Even IE8 doesn't support Canvas directly.

Comment: I do have to do quite a bit of dom manipulation based on the user's interactions.  I use the Telerik RadControls all over the page too which do alot of dom manipulation.

Comment: so let me ask you this, if i had moved some of my dom manipulation intense actions to something like an iframe the number of dom elements would be dramactically smaller and therefore do you think it would be faster or even slower dealing with the iframe?>

Comment: If you have a lot of DOM manipulations to do to a particular part of the tree, pull that out, do the work on it outside the DOM, then put the whole thing back.

Comment: thats an intersting idea...can u do JQuery stuff on just strings tho?

Comment: Here's an example in Mootools. The author says it's easy to port to jQuery... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987889/speeding-up-jquery-empty-or-replacewith-functions-when-dealing-with-large-dom

Comment: any thoughts about the iframe tho

Comment: jQuery's clone() is used to move sections of the DOM around. Maybe you can work on the clone until you're ready to put it back.

Comment: Mainly, when I refer to DOM manipulations, I'm referring to the number of times you touch any kind of dom element, on screen or off screen. I had this somewhat similar question in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895992/896012#896012 , Where that person is using jQuery to find elements every time through a loop, when he could have cached the first result. I can't make more specific suggestions since I don't see your code, but try and look for places where you're performing idempotent operations more often than you need to, or find ways to combine multiple operations into a single one.

Comment: You might also keep in mind that a lot of performance is just perception. What exactly is it you see unfolding on screen that makes you feel like it's being too slow? Sometimes a solution is as simple as adding a progress bar, or moving the parsing and execution of the javascript until after the page has rendered, and CSS applied.

Comment: "so let me ask you this, if i had moved some of my dom manipulation intense actions to something like an iframe the number of dom elements would be dramactically smaller and therefore do you think it would be faster or even slower dealing with the iframe?" just going on gut instinct, I don't think it would be faster, as an iframe is still part of the dom, and simply moving the location of the dom operations doesn't reduce the number of them.

Comment: But it might make it *feel* faster by deferring the costly operations to a different thread, so the page can continue to render, unbothered.

Answer (score 2):

Some pretty regular gotchas pertain almost exclusively to the DOM, which is slow accross browsers. Try to user innerHTML wherever possible. It's not the standards-compliant way of doing things, but it is *by far* the fastest.

If you're looping through DOM elements using something like the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < domNodes.length; i++) { ... }
```

Note that every time you request the length of a `NodeList`, a rather expensive lookup operation is performed. You're better off caching the length of the `NodeList` as follows:

```
for (var i = 0, il = domNodes.length; i < il; i++) { ... }
```

The performance improvements here are incredible. [Robert Nyman](http://robertnyman.com/2008/04/11/javascript-loop-performance/) did an interesting comparison of `for` loops. If you've never heard of this, the performance boost might surprise you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent google tech talk video on javascript optimization by javascript guru Nicholas C. Zakas
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU

He advises you to use local variables to limit scope lookup, keep javascript css style changes to a minimum(change classes instead) and do them in batches if you have to to reduce browser re-rendering, and lots of other great tips :)

Comment: That's a great talk. I have Souders' first book. I'll have to get the new one.

Comment: also check the YUI Teather: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/ there are talks about JS, AJAX, performance, style and philosophy of JS from Douglas Crockford, John Resig (jQuery), Nicholas Zakas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Attach and detach events as needed and do not use behaviors. Also create threads to speed up UI using setTimeout and setInterval. I do this all the time to prevent IU choppiness.